# Kineticjs load json canvas

Tags: json, canvas, load, kineticjs

I always got the error:

"TypeError: Kinetic[type] is not a constructor" 
"ReferenceError: reference to undefined property obj.nodeType"

when i try to load one json.

```
json = stage.toJSON();

stage = Kinetic.Node.create(json, 'myCanvas');
```

the method _createNode from Kineticjs 4.3.3

```
var no = new Kinetic[type](obj.attrs);
```

on my canvas I have a simple group

```
var circle1 = new Kinetic.Circle({
                x: 40,
                y: 50,
                radius: 42,
                fill: 'white',
                stroke: 'black',
                strokeWidth: 1,
                draggable: false
            });

var polygon1Tab1 = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon({
                        x: 40,
                        y: 50,
                        radius: 27,
                        sides: 4,
                        stroke: 'black',
                        strokeWidth: 4,
                        draggable: false
                  });
                  polygon1Tab1.rotateDeg(45);


var group1 = new Kinetic.Group({
                                  draggable: true,
                              });

group1.add(circle1.clone());
group1.add(polygon1.clone());
```

Answer (score 0):

What is "polygon1" here?

```
group1.add(polygon1.clone());
```

I created this example. Everything forks fine: http://jsfiddle.net/lavrton/N3UPX/

Answer (score 0):

'**polygon1**' It's just one name ... a change!!!!
I take your code and place to run and continue with the same error!
when i  print the json I noticed that it has an error!

he puts this   `"children": "[]"` and should not have quotes in brackets
if I copy and put my string this fixed string corrected wheel normal!!
I made a method to remove the error .... Now I'm with an error

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'


var json = polygonLayer.toJSON();
json = json.replace('"children":"', '"children":');
json = json.substring(0, json.length-2) + json.substring(json.length-1, json.length);
```

whereas using the same fixed string works!

I'm using version 4.3.3

this work

```
var json = '{"attrs":{"clearBeforeDraw":true,"visible":true,"listening":true,"opacity":1,"x":0,"y":0,"scale":{"x":1,"y":1},"rotation":0,"offset":{"x":0,"y":0},"draggable":false,"dragOnTop":true},"nodeType":"Layer","children":[{\"attrs\": {\"width\": 600, \"height\": 400, \"cornerRadius\": 0, \"fillEnabled\": true, \"strokeEnabled\": true, \"shadowEnabled\": true, \"dashArrayEnabled\": true, \"fillPriority\": \"color\", \"visible\": true, \"listening\": true, \"opacity\": 1, \"x\": 0, \"y\": 0, \"scale\": {\"x\": 1, \"y\": 1}, \"rotation\": 0, \"offset\": {\"x\": 0, \"y\": 0}, \"draggable\": false, \"dragOnTop\": true, \"fill\": \"white\"}, \"nodeType\": \"Shape\", \"shapeType\": \"Rect\"}]}';
layer = Kinetic.Node.create(json, 'canvas');
```

but this dont work

```
var json = layer.toJSON();
layer = Kinetic.Node.create(json, 'canvas');
```